# cakePhp-Session and DB-table modification

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I can access a logged in user with `$this->Auth->user();` in the controllers. That’s so far clear. 
If I add some new DB field in the users table, clear the cake cache and logs in again then still I can not find the new field in the returned user record with `$this->Auth->user()`. This field is also missing in the session file on the server. What is it which I am missing?

Comment: You're absolutely, definitely logging out, ending your session, verifying that your sessions has ended, and then adding the new field and logging back in? And you're definitely using Cache sessions, not database sessions?

Comment: I am not very sure if I have logged me out before I added the new db field in the users table. But I am very sure that I am using Cache sessions. Otherwise I would not be able to see the session file. Although I am unsure if I have logged me out before I expect that at least that I see the changes after I have logged me out and relogged in. This would apply also for all users.